# How to get the Roblox Proximity to open a store Frame

Tags: lua, roblox, proximity

I read through the Roblox Developer Hub on how to make a ProximityPrompt work, and I can get it to do certain things, but I want to be able to open in game gui stores with one. I can't find how to call into the Frame to make it visible, and I can't find how to get the Frame to look for the correct trigger.

Below is what I added to the Frame localScript

```
local prompt = game:GetService("ProximityPromptService")

local button = game.Workspace.MinerStore.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:WaitForChild()

local function prompt(PromptObject, player) 
    frame.Visible = not frame.Visible
```

And then this is what my Prompt script shows.

```
local frame = game.StarterGui.Miners:WaitForChild("Frame")

game.Workspace.MinerStore.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    --game.StarterGui.Miners.Frame:Connect(function(player)
    --  frame.Visible = not frame.Visible
    --end)
    
end)
```

I took all of this right from the developer hub and tried to make it my own, but for reasons I don't understand the two don't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commented out code shows that you are making a common mistake. UI that is placed in the [StarterGui](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterGui) acts as a template. It is copied into each player's [PlayerGui](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/PlayerGui) when their character spawns. You appear to be trying to modify the UI template, not the actual UI that the specific player sees.

Since a ProximityPrompt can be observed in a LocalScript, you can directly listen for the trigger in the UI LocalScript.

```
local prompt = game.Workspace.MinerStore.ProximityPrompt
local frame = script.Parent

prompt.Triggered:Connect(function()
    frame.Visible = true
end)
```

Comment: I was able to get it working with some mods to make it serviceable for what I am doing. Thanks.